# Bring header on top of everything

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On this page http://goo.gl/m2s1dA

I want to bring the whole header layer "header-container" as below on top of everything and anything inside of "container-site" should appear behind the header when scrolling.

Below is my code.

Full width div

```
.header-container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Fixed width div to center align header and some styling

```
.header-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cc6666;
    height: 263px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 1140px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Then body of the page

```
.container-site {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1140px;
    padding-top: 280px;
}
```

Currently only the headings (h1, h2, h3) are appearing behind the header. I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: what is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i m guessing you want content inside "container-site" to appear over everything. add these to .container-site{  position: relative; z-index: 9999;    background-color: white; //added this to show that it's appearing everything}

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you want the header to be above all content and fixed to the top of page. In your code, the header-container is inside a fixed parent:

```
<div class="glass">
   <div class="header-container">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

what you have to do is simply add z-index to the parent of the header like this:

```
.glass { z-index: 1; }
```

This should fix your problem however, your header is transparent and that creates visual problems when text is under the header elements...

Answer (score 1):

Header is on top but can't figure out it because it is transparent. give `.header-container {background:#fff}` and see how it looks like.